# How to detect all the connected neighboring pixels which have same color value in opencv

Tags: image-processing, opencv, c++

I should be able to input a pixel position and get all the same coloured(in my case it should be black) pixels which are connected to it. How to do this in opencv with c++. Simply the output pixels should be connected to each other with color black. FindContours() method does not work as it cannot be feeded with a pixel.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`floodFill`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#floodfill). From the documentation:

> The functions `floodFill` fill a connected component starting from the seed point with the specified color. The connectivity is determined by the color/brightness closeness of the neighbor pixels. The pixel at (x,y) is considered to belong to the repainted domain if: [...]
>
> Use these functions to either mark a connected component with the specified color in-place, **or build a mask** and then extract the contour, or copy the region to another image, and so on.

You're probably interested in this flag parameter:

> `FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY` If set, the function does not change the image ( newVal is ignored), and only fills the mask with the value specified in bits 8-16 of flags as described above. This option only make sense in function variants that have the mask parameter.

Comment: floodFill() does not return the connected pixels but just replace their color. That is not what expected.

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga: Read the second paragraph again: floodFill can "*either mark a connected component with the specified color in-place, or build a mask*". You're probably looking for `FLOODFILL_MASK_ONLY`.

Comment: Can u please describe about this Mask? I do not understand what is this Mask or what is the usage of it

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga: Which part of the linked documentation did you not understand? It says "*On output, pixels in the mask corresponding to filled pixels in the image are set to 1 or to the a value specified in flags*...". That seems clear to me.

Comment: What does this mask do? For what it is used?

Comment: It is used to find the connected set of pixels with the same color, containing the seed pixel. Please read the linked documentation. There's a sample, too.